# MacOS build via copy app software installation

Tags: macos, installation

I created my app for `macOS` via `Copy app`, when I click on the file of type application app starts.

How can I make that application be installed.

That is, even when I restart the pc, I would like the application when the pc turns on to be executed when it starts.

How can I do?

Comment: It is not about SwiftUI. Add application to start up items in Preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is installed right now, you don't need to do anything more.

Mac apps are basically a folder with the extension `.app`, e.g `Xcode.app`. In Apple terms it's a `package`. You can see this by right-clicking any app and using `Show Package Contents`. To uninstall an app, delete it, that's all.

To start the app at launch you can use the "Login Items" of your user account in System Preferences > Users & Groups

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this part correctly:
Mac apps are basically a standalone folder full of stuff.

So if I want to uninstall apps, should I just delete the folder with the installation file?

Isn't there a way to make the user be prompted that when they click on the app file, whether to enter it in the login?

Comment: See edited post & yes there's a way to programmatically add the app to login items but that's a separate question you can either research or ask here in another post. This might help https://medium.com/@hoishing/adding-login-items-for-macos-7d76458f6495